# AzureDevops REST API - how to cancel a specific deployment

Tags: rest, azure-devops

I want to cancel a specific deployment in Azure Devops using their REST API.  I found an article where I can set the whole environment to cancelled, but I just want to cancel a specific deployment (not the latest).  I cant find anything in their API reference under release or deployments.

Here is the API ref for the update of a release environment:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release%20environment?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API you find is right. You can specify a certain deployment using `releaseId` and `environmentId` in URI Parameters. If you want to cancel the deployment, set the `status` to `canceled` in Request Body.

You can find the `releaseId` and `environmentId` in the URL of the release page:

[image]

Comment: - thank you.  The following code worked (powershell)

`$body = @"
  {
    "status": "canceled",
    "scheduledDeploymentTime": null,
    "comment": null,
    "variables": {}
    }
"@

  Write-Host $body

  $uri = "$($collectionUrl)/$($project)/_apis/Release/releases/$($cancelRelease.id)/environments/$($cancelEnvironment.id)?api-version=6.0-preview.6"

  Write-Host $uri
  Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method PATCH -ContentType "application/json"  -Body $body`

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/deployments/cancel

This document may be helpful for you

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/{deploymentName}/cancel?api-version=2020-06-01
```